# Ibiza in November, all the market will be closed?

Tags: spain, islands

I'm looking to stay in Ibiza on 14/November for a day but I read that maybe the most beaches are closed, and the island is desert, the market is closed on this month with a very bad weather, but I don't know if it's truth. As turist, should I avoid the island on this month?

Comment: Please don't delete posts and then re-post them a few minutes later but edit them instead. Your question is clearer now though, only the last part is still opion-based but the rest is answerable.

Comment: I rewrote the full question, edit would not have been enough for the question deleted so was I've re-created it and it already had 2 votes do close so was bad formatted before, right?

Comment: It is fine now, but next time on a young question you can fully re-write it when editing, that is preferred. The close votes are no problem then, as I would have taken mine back as soon as seeing your edit.

Comment: What market are you enquiring about?

Comment: When I say market I mean the local market in general, right? If was talking about Italy we can say that market closes for the lunch time because a lot of places closes on this time and that's a bad moment for tourists.

Answer (score 8):

> most beaches are closed

Beaches are of public access. They are not "closed", you can go as you want. The difference will be that there will be no services like lifeguards, beach bars and restaurants and the like. But most probably, it will be not very cold but cold enough that you will not enjoy taking off your clothes to sunbathe or take a bath.

> the market is closed

Believe it or not, apart from tourists there are people who actually live in Ibiza and they do their shopping all the year round. That said, november is low season so many tourist ammenities and facilities (hotels, discos, bars and restaurants) will be closed. But there will be enough left open to avoid starvation.

> month with a very bad weather

In general it is not often stormy/rainy (but there may be some storm or rain), but it will be, without doubt, far colder than July (bless God). Anyway, you can always check any weather service.

In conclussion: you can go to Ibiza, but you will get some holidays that are nothing like the ones you would have in Summer. They will be way more quieter/calmer. I would avoid beach hotels and look for hotels inside towns.